# I'm having trouble starting up my first python nameko service

Tags: python, pip, nameko

I'm getting the following stack trace:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "", line 783, in exec_module
File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\nameko\cli\run.py", line 4, in 
eventlet.monkey_patch()  # noqa (code before rest of imports)
File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\eventlet\patcher.py", line 334, in monkey_patch
fix_threading_active()
File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\eventlet\patcher.py", line 331, in fix_threading_active
_os.register_at_fork(
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'register_at_fork'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in *run_code

exec(code, run_globals)

File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\nameko.exe_*main**.py", line 7, in 
File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\nameko\cli\main.py", line 
112, in main
args.main(args)
File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\nameko\cli\commands.py", line 
109, in main
from .run import main
File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "", line 152, in **exit**
File "", line 107, in release
RuntimeError: cannot release un-acquired lock

this is my pip freeze :
amqp==2.6.1
astroid==2.4.2
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.4.3
dnspython==1.16.0
eventlet==0.27.0
greenlet==0.4.16
idna==2.10
isort==5.5.2
kombu==4.6.11
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
mccabe==0.6.1
mock==4.0.2
monotonic==1.5
nameko==2.12.0
path==15.0.0
path.py==12.5.0
pylint==2.6.0
PyYAML==5.3.1
requests==2.24.0
six==1.15.0
toml==0.10.1
urllib3==1.25.10
vine==1.3.0
virtualenv==20.0.31
Werkzeug==1.0.1
wrapt==1.12.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the stack trace you provided here, it is evident you're working within a Windows environment. `nameko` does not support Windows-based environments. There is an [open issue in the `nameko` GitHub repository](https://github.com/nameko/nameko/issues/626) requesting support for Windows (among others), but there hasn't been any movement on this since April 2019.

Specifically, Python's [`os.register_at_fork`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.register_at_fork) method, the one that's causing your error ("`AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'register_at_fork'`"), is only available on Unix-based systems.

Comment: That would explain why I'm only able to execute it within a docker environment. Thank you very much!